# Google maps remove labels or grayout area except some regions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi i am using google map and i want your views for the following question.

is it possible to hide or grayout all the area except some other in googlemap?

if Yes, then please give me a hand for this problem.

i have tried but didn't found any solution till now.

here is my [**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dhavalbharadva/h3Pv3/)

in that demo i want to grayout/hide labels of all the area with no markers.

here is the sample code which i am using to pin the marker on map.

JS CODE:

```
<script>
var infowindow;
var map;
var myLatLng = [];

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var obj = {
        "JobRecord": [{
            "ApplyUrl": "test",
                "GeoLocations": {
                "GeoLocationRecord": [{
                    "Latitude": "21.543333",
                        "Longitude": "39.172777"
                }, {
                    "Latitude": "21.299135",
                        "Longitude": "40.428313"
                }]
            },
                "JobId": "493743",
                "JobTitle": "Sales Associate",
                "Locations": {
                "LocationRecord": [{
                    "Group": "Saudi Arabia",
                        "Title": "Taif"
                }, {
                    "Group": "Saudi Arabia",
                        "Title": "Jeddah"
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "ApplyUrl": "test",
                "GeoLocations": {
                "GeoLocationRecord": {
                    "Latitude": "55.755826",
                        "Longitude": "37.617300"
                }
            },
                "JobId": "492725",
                "JobTitle": "Business Director - Starbucks - Russia",
                "Locations": {
                "LocationRecord": {
                    "Group": "Russia",
                        "Title": "Moscow"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "ApplyUrl": "test",
                "GeoLocations": {
                "GeoLocationRecord": {
                    "Latitude": "25.271139",
                        "Longitude": "55.307485"
                }
            },
                "JobId": "492730",
                "JobTitle": "Vice President - Victoria's Secret",
                "Locations": {
                "LocationRecord": {
                    "Group": "UAE",
                        "Title": "Dubai"
                }
            }
        }]
    };
    var jobs = obj.JobRecord;
    for (var i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
        if (jobs[i].GeoLocations.length != 0) {
            var geoLocationRecord = jobs[i].GeoLocations.GeoLocationRecord;
            var myjobs = new Array();

            var single = new Object();

            if (geoLocationRecord.length === undefined) {

                single.JobId = jobs[i].JobId;
                single.JobTitle = jobs[i].JobTitle;
                single.Locations = jobs[i].Locations.LocationRecord;

                var search = [geoLocationRecord.Latitude, geoLocationRecord.Longitude, single];
                isLocationFree(search);
            } else {
                for (var j = 0; j < geoLocationRecord.length; j++) {
                    single[j] = new Object();

                    single[j].JobId = jobs[i].JobId;
                    single[j].JobTitle = jobs[i].JobTitle;
                    single[j].Locations = jobs[i].Locations.LocationRecord[j];

                    var search = [geoLocationRecord[j].Latitude, geoLocationRecord[j].Longitude, single[j]];
                    isLocationFree(search);
                } //finish inner loop
            }
        } //finish if condition
    } //finish loop

    for (var x = 0; x < myLatLng.length; x++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(myLatLng[x][0]),
        parseFloat(myLatLng[x][1]));
        bounds.extend(latlng);

        createMarker(myLatLng[x], latlng);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
        if (map.getZoom() > 16) map.setZoom(3);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
    });
}

function createMarker(jobs, latlng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: createMessage(jobs)
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    return marker;
}

function createMessage(jobs) {
    console.log(jobs);
    console.log("Total==>" + (Number(jobs.length) - 2));

    if (jobs[2].Locations !== undefined) {
        var locationTitle = jobs[2].Locations.Title;
    } else {
        var locationTitle = "";
    }

    var message = '';
    message += '<div id="popupContent">' +
        '<strong id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + (Number(jobs.length) - 2) + " Vacancies in " + locationTitle + '</strong>' +
        '<br><br>';
    for (var y = 2; y < jobs.length; y++) {
        message += '<a href="http://jobsearch.alshaya.com/cau/en/job/' + jobs[y].JobId + '" target="_blank">' + jobs[y].JobTitle + '</a><br>';

    }
    message += '</div>';

    return message;
}

function isLocationFree(search) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myLatLng.length; i++) {
        if (myLatLng[i][0] === search[0] && myLatLng[i][1] === search[1]) {
            myLatLng[i].push(search[2]);
            return true;
        }
    }
    myLatLng.push(search);
    return myLatLng;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    initialize();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591937/google-maps-api-v3-gray-out-or-remove-states

Comment: You can also check this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18867/is-it-possible-to-gray-out-a-google-maps-map-except-for-some-area but I find these examples/solutions a bit clumsy.

Comment: In any case, I think you will need geometry data. KML Layer seems to be the best option to me.

Comment: @MrUpsidown how can i implement KML Layer with my current code.?

Comment: Check the example provided by @Geocodezip in my first link. You can check the code and the links to the doc. Also you can check this answer for a local version of the geometry data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302002/google-map-as-a-vector-map/21302964#21302964 You need to find the right geometry dataset. What do you want to hide? You mentioned *greyout all the area* and *greyout labels*. You can greyout/hide road labels and other features for the whole map, not for a specific region/country. You can greyout an area with a polygon, based on geometry data.

Comment: Instead of greying out other regions, did you consider highlighting the ones you are interested in?

Comment: @MrUpsidown currently i am getting the data dynamically from xml feed and based on that markers are display in map and i want to show/highlight only area with the markers are in map other region should be greyout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that quite easily by using a [**Fusion Table Layer**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables).

I consider here the mentioned "area" or "regions" as countries - I guess you simply want to gray out the countries that is not present in your XML-feed?

Here I have hardcoded the countries from your example - Russia, Saudia Arabia and United Arab Emirates. You must yourself create the logic to exclude the countries you meet in your feed.

```js
function greyoutWorld() {
    var world_geometry = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: '1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk',
            //select all but russia, saudi arabia and united arab emirates
            where: "ISO_2DIGIT NOT IN ('RU', 'SA', 'AE')"
        },
        //add some grey color to cover the rest of the world
        styles: [{
            polygonOptions: {
                fillColor: "#dadada",
                strokeColor: "#ebebeb",
                strokeWeight: "int"
            },
            polylineOptions: {
                strokeColor: "#rrggbb",
                strokeWeight: "int"  
            }
        }],
        map: map,
        suppressInfoWindows: true
    });
}
```

The result looks like this :

[image]

Forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/QUPdZ/**

---

**Update**

Regarding the "red circle markers", this feature is built into the Fusion Table layer code, and cannot be suppressed. See the [**documentation**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTablesSetup), under "Limits" :

> When looking at the map, you may notice:
>    * The ten largest-area components of a multi-geometry are shown.
>    * When zoomed farther out, tables with more than 500 features will show dots (not lines or polygons).

The workaround is to add

```
minZoom: 2
```

to the map options, like in this fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/LVRp2/**

The country geometry Fusion Table - World Country Boundaries.kml - is public and accessible here :

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk.

An alternative, same source I guess - World Country Boundaries.csv - can be found here :

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1uL8KJV0bMb7A8-SkrIe0ko2DMtSypHX52DatEE4.

Both works with the above fiddle.

Comment: +1.  This is probably the best solution you'll find, since the labels in the map are within images and thus not editable.

Comment: I think this the result that i want but how can i access fusion table that you have created with data.

Comment: One more think when i am zooming out the map at that time it shows red circle markers which comes from fusion table so how i can disable that markers.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this in v2 of googlemaps by overlaying a shape overlay (i.e. a polygon that encompasses the whole world BUT the area I want shown).

In the end my area was fairly complex so I ended up generating it with google maps and saving the shape in a separate .kmz file, you will be able to achieve the result both ways.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xHKB7/6/) of adding the perimeter one coordinate pair at a time.

The [`KmlLayer` function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#KmlLayer) allows you to load a .kmz you have generated from google map;  see also this answer on Stackoverflow: [Using KMZ Files in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810332/using-kmz-files-in-google-maps)

In google maps, follow this tutorial to generate the kml

Comment: Can you show me example code for that? or appropriate source to find the sample code to implement.

Comment: I added some references

Comment: Thanks for your effort but this is not the solution that i want.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a recap here.

While you have a few solutions explained here, they all require **external data** that btw. is hard to maintain and incomplete (I still could not find a Fusion Table world boundaries dataset that is complete).

I personnaly don't think this is a good way of "highlighting" where the positions are, and I think this is overcomplicated.

Another possibility would be to use a [marker clusterer](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries) which is very good to highlight where most of your positions are. And it's easy to implement.

What we **don't know** is what features you need from the Google Maps API. Maybe you should consider using another service that might allow easier manipulation of boundaries data. Did you already check [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/) for instance?

I know my answer is not really a *solution* to your question, but it might help you ask yourself the right question: *Is greying out some areas on the map the best option to highlight where the positions are?*

Comment: I cannot see why one should not take benefit of public data, in this case datasets most propably created / uploaded by google employees. It is not harder to "maintain" than to copy the tables. Furthermore, I think the geometry does a good job - what makes them incomplete? Your considerations are somehow good, but this is not a perfect world, and I suspect OP just wants a nice feature, not a rocket science project :)

Comment: Check the different datasets available and tell me if you find one that is complete: no country missing, all areas covered, etc. Another point I didn't mention: performance. It's not lightweight at all. It might be a nice feature as you say, but I can't see the benefits when I think about all the points I mentioned.